# Finding 4 perpendicular unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The question:
Find 4 perpendicular unit vectors whose components are all either 1/2 or -1/2.

I' m just having trouble understanding how to do this.

NOTE:
The dimension is not specified.

Comment: In which dimension?

Comment: It isn't specified.

Comment: Hint: start with $(1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$ and change *suitable* pairs of $+$ to $-$...

Comment: it has to be at least four since there can be no solution in a dimension lower than that.

Comment: Yes I did that, but I don't believe that's all I have to do is it?

Comment: Well you can start in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and start brute forcing as one method. Here's a pair: $(1/2, 1/2, -1/2, -1/2), (1/2, -1/2, - 1/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: To ease up the calculation, just use $\pm1$ as each component... Once orthogonal, multiply each vector by $1/2$.

Comment: Don't I have to do something with the Pythagorean theorom.  Honestly this text book is really hard to decipher.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, this book is awful.

Answer (score 2):

One vector could be $$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end {matrix}\right)$$
Then the others can be 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\-\frac 12\end {matrix}\right)$$$$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\\frac 12\\-\frac 12\end {matrix}\right)$$$$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\\frac 12\end {matrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

First, deduce the number of entries. If a **unit**-vector has $n$ entries which are all $\pm 1/2$, what is $n$? Use the "Pythagorean theorem".

You should find that $n=4$. There are only $2^4=16$ vectors that you can work with, you just need $4$ that are perpendicular to each other. "Trial and error" is a reasonable way to go here.

Comment: Wait, do I really only need to write these vectors, no required equations once I know what they are.

Comment: How can I know for sure they are perpendicular.

Comment: Check the dot product of every pair

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are perpendicular if and only if their inner product equals zero. That is what you should use to solve this. You can just work with vectors whose entries are either $1$ or $-1$ since multiplication by a scalar does not affect orthogonality.

If you can't come up with a solution, you can Google something called "a Hadamard matrix" and you'll find one.